# Wcf Serialization - Why doesn't this base class have public members?

Tags: wcf, serialization

I have a derived base class with the following fields

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.3752.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/members")]
public partial class Members {
    
    private string keyField;
    private string noField;
    private string old_Group_Account_NumberField;
    private string nameField;
    private string global_Dimension_2_CodeField;
    private string iD_NoField;
    private string payroll_Staff_NoField;
    private string fOSA_AccountField;
    private string sectionField;
    private System.DateTime registration_DateField;
    private bool registration_DateFieldSpecified;
    private string regionField;
    private string group_NameField;
    private decimal net_ChangeField;
    private bool net_ChangeFieldSpecified;
    private decimal eloan_LimitField;
    private bool eloan_LimitFieldSpecified;
    private string mPESA_Mobile_NoField;
        
    /// <remarks/>
    public string Key {
        get {
            return this.keyField;
        }
        set {
            this.keyField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string No {
        get {
            return this.noField;
        }
        set {
            this.noField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string Old_Group_Account_Number {
        get {
            return this.old_Group_Account_NumberField;
        }
        set {
            this.old_Group_Account_NumberField = value;
        }
    }...
```

This is a web reference and trying to use it as below

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Member.Members m(Member.Members mm);
    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

And

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{

    public Member.Members m(Member.Members mm)
    {
        return mm;
    }
}
```

and this is my wsdl

[image]

What is giving me a headache is:
Why are the base private members serialized in the wsdl instead of the public ones? Why do the fields in the wsdl have an extra string 'field'? How do i do away with that?

Comment: Have you added [DataMember] to the property of the class?

Comment: This class 'Members' is inherited from a web reference so any changes to the class will get discarded when i update the web reference.

Comment: It may be that [DataMember] is not added to the server-side class, because I see that your property does not have [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]. Normally, the property in the generated proxy class will have [System.Runtime. Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()].You need to check the server-side.

Comment: No other problems, the field field is automatically generated and will not affect.